# iPhone applicationDidFinishLaunching called once in simulator

Tags: iphone, nsapplication

I put an NSLog statement inside my applicationDidFinishLaunching method. I build and run and see the log output. Then if I hit the home button (in the simulator) and restart the app, I don't see the log output.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the debugger is no longer attached once you hit the home button.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm testing some user defaults loading and it was confusing the heck out of me.